# How can I start a VM in headless mode from the VirtualBox GUI?

Tags: virtualbox, headless

In the [release notes for VirtualBox v4.2.0](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) it notes one of the changes as:

> GUI: allow starting of headless VMs from the GUI

However, I can't seem to find how to start the VM in headless mode from the GUI.  How is this done?

Comment: Very good question, I was wondering this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took some searching, but according to [this blog at Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/what_s_new_in_oracle):

> Simply hold down Shift when launching the VM from the Manager.  It's that easy.

And that seems to work for me.  Now they just need to document it in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

From VirtualBox 5.0 onwards, there's a dropdown next to the "Start" button which features a way to start in Headless mode

[image]